# How do I keep the user's iPhone's display on?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

So, I was looking for a way to keep the user's iPhone display on for a clock app. I found `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;` but that keeps the device from locking all of the time. I tried to `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;` when the application goes into the background, but that doesn't work. How can I safely keep the user's device from sleeping *while my app is running*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alter the `idleTimerDisabled` property whenever your app changes its active state - if you're going to be backgrounded, re-enable the timer, and when you regain control, disable the timer again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution, using XCode 6.2.

[iPhone - phone goes to sleep even if idleTimerDisabled is YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679814/iphone-phone-goes-to-sleep-even-if-idletimerdisabled-is-yes/29256860#29256860)

Basically, even now, in 2015, the only way to safely make sure that the device doesn't go to sleep is to *repeatedly* call a piece of code to keep the device awake.

```
-(void)callEveryTwentySeconds
{
    //  DON'T let the device go to sleep during our sync
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
}
```

Comment: Some questions are everlasting.