# iOS: idleTimerDisabled = YES works only until ImagePicker was used

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uiapplication

I have an **iPad** survey tool as an internal enterprise application. I prevent screen locking with setting `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];` at `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of the application delegate.

That works fine until I use the `imagePicker` to take an image. After that, the `idleTimer` is activated again. I have tried to disable it after the image was taken but that doesn't work.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11077931/702961) I found the hint that setting the required device capabilities in the info.plist could help. But so far it didn't. I have just added all camera specific flags.

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Marcus

Comment: have you tried toggling the idleTimerDisabled after the imagePicker - meaning you enable AND disable it following the imagePicker?  (vs. just setIdleTimerDisabled:YES.)

Comment: Where and how you **setIdleTimerDisabled: NO**? Where and how you **setIdleTimerDisabled: YES** after the imagePicker is dismissed. May be providing code will help.

Comment: I never set the idle timer to NO, this happens automatically if you are using the UIImagePicker. Looks like an iOS bug.
After the image is taken I try to disable the idle timer in -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info, but it doesn't work.

You can only try it out if the iPad is disconnected from Xcode, as XCode keeps the application enabled all the time.

Comment: Have you tried `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;` also?

Comment: @MarcusFranzen, did my answer below work for your app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to reset the UIApplication idleTimerDisabled like so:

```
- (void)resetIdleTimerDisabled
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(resetIdleTimerDisabled) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self performSelector:@selector(resetIdleTimerDisabled) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
    }];
}
```

What I suspect is happening is that internally `UIImagePickerController` sets `UIApplication.idleTimerDisabled` to `YES` to keep the camera from sleeping. When finished (after the delegate methods are called and apparently even after the animation completion block is executed), the `UIImagePickerController` sets `UIApplication.idleTimerDisabled` back to `NO`. Instead, it only should do this if the value was previously `NO`.

I filed a bug report with Apple.  See [UIImageViewControllerBug](https://github.com/jamiemcd/rdar/tree/master/UIImagePickerControllerBug) sample project.

Answer (score 1):

Jamie's solution looks good! I'm just not a big fan of `afterDelay:` methods:)

The issue is in the PhotoLibrary framework: it disables the `idleTimer` prior to starting preview stream from camera and enables it again when tearing it down regardless of the previous value.

If you feel more adventures and want solution that works throughout the app, here is one involving swizzling: https://gist.github.com/zats/1a4aece697075478b44a

Tested for both cases when `idleTimer` disabled or enabled prior to showing image picker. My solution does not observe `idleTimerDisabled` while image picker is presented.

P.S. the same issue happens when using dictation feature (bug in `UIDictationController`)
(@[jamie-mcdaniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496504/jamie-mcdaniel) if you would be so kind to update your bug report)

Comment: I updated my bug report to include UIDictationController. rdar://16940667