# Xcode makes the screen never gets locked

Tags: xcode

I observed a strange behaviour that If I run the app via XCode while the phone is **connected using USB** the app never lets the iphone home screen to timeout and lock after 1 minute.

But If I **disconnect the USB** and launch the app then the screen goes lock after 1 minute.

Is this a default behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible because xCode can not connect (and install, debug) while the phone is locked.

BTW you can alter this behavior in code:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Swift

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

Comment: idleTimerDisabled = YES; or idleTimerDisabled = NO; ?

Comment: disable=YES == will not lock

Comment: disable=NO; will it guarentee the phone will be allowed to lock?

Comment: no guarentee, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679814/iphone-phone-goes-to-sleep-even-if-idletimerdisabled-is-yes