# idleTimerDisabled doesn't work (Keep iPad screen from going to sleep)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I have to download a very large file on the iPad. (iOS5, iOS6)

To keep the iPad screen from going in to sleep I use:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

But it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try doing:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = NO;
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

[See this answer for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058717/idletimerdisabled-not-working-since-iphone-3-0)